# Why would I get a PHP/PDOException complaining that it can't make a Postgres connection because it can't find an app-local certificate file?

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl, pdo, certificate

I've got a PHP app with Postgresql for the datastore, and just migrated the db to a new managed offering provider. Now when I try and run the app on my local development machine (macOS 10.12.6), I encounter the following error trying to connect to the newly situated db:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not open certificate file
> "/var/root/.postgresql/postgresql.crt": Permission denied

There's a couple of interesting things about this:

1. If I try to connect to the same remote database via the `psql` client, I have no problem, it drops me straight into a psql prompt where I can query away at the DB to my heart's content.
2. I can execute PHP cli scripts that connect to the remote DB and query it without problem. PDO only throws an exception if I'm calling the connection code through a script invoked via an http request through a local Apache 2.4 server.
3. I am not at all shocked that permission is denied to access resources in `/var/root`, but  I *am* shocked that anything expected to run in userland would ever be checking there. It seems like permission *should* be denied by default for its contents, even if there was a `.postgresql/` subdirectory there (which there isn't).

#1 suggests this is not a pg_hba.conf or other client whitelist or network issue. #3 probably suggests perhaps I should have Apache switch to a non-root user, I'd guess, but beyond that I'm not sure what to make of it, and at any rate I have not placed a ~/.postgresql or postgresql.crt anywhere.

#2 suggests Apache2+libphp7.so doesn't know where to look for postgresql client certs... but the php binary does? This feels like the big clue, but I have no idea why it would be the case or how to fix it.

What are some next steps I could take to figure out how to get the web app connecting?

**EDIT:**

Prompted by the comment by @jjanes below, it occurred to me to try two things:

a) changing the apache config so that it was running as my personal user to see if the connection worked

b) trying to make a `psql` connection as root to see if that worked

When both did, that suggested to me that maybe the error message *isn't* complaining that it can't find a certificate for root (but somehow knows where to look for my personal account), it's that it's freaked out that it couldn't even muster permissions to check under /var/root.

So I did `chmod /var/root o+x` and `mkdir /var/root/.postgresql/` and... it's fine. It didn't need the cert, just needed to have permission to look for it.

This feels like a bug for the `sslmode=require` level of things, but I'm happy to have a workaround. And I'd still be interested to hear suggestions of other ways to address situations like it.

Comment: "If I try to connect to the same remote database via the psql client, I have no problem,"  Are you running the psql client as the same user as the one running apache (apparently, root)?

Comment: @jjanes: that's a great observation—no, I ran psql and php shell scripts via a personal account with my name, `west`. To see what would happen, I just restarted apache running as `west` and… the session handler freaks out b/c it can't write to `/var/tmp`, but sure enough, the postgres connection goes through!  I still don't know why, though. There's no `postgresql.crt` or `~/.postgresql/` directory, so I don't know how to make this work for `root` (or `www` or `daemon` if I make a dedicated service user).

Comment: Set the `sslmode` connection string parameter to `require` so that the client does not insist in verifying the server certificate.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Good thought, I should probably have included in the question that I'm using sslmode=require in the connection string both in PHP app code that throws the connection error and in the cli-invoked app code that succeeds.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be a bug in PDO and is a pain to solve when you are running PHP inside a container